# In php, how do I get the text/plain value of send() method of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have no idea how to get the "Hello World!" in PHP for the following Javascript codes.

 
I know I can use $_POST[''] if the content-type was "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", but not for "text/plain".

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'example.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
xhr.send('Hello World!');
```

Answer (score 8):

This PHP will read the raw data from the request body:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Line 3:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

isn't required as posting plain text will set the content type to text/plain;charset=UTF-8
http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method

Comment: Although I agree that the "correct" standard practice is to always format form data properly, the "php://input" bit is an interesting detail worth noting. And more information about it can be found with a web search: [link](http://www.google.com/search?q="php://input")

Comment: Where is the problem with sending POST-data as plain text? I never read that the HTTP-standard requires POST-data to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", which is used by e.g PHP and browsers to communicate one level higher than HTTP

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for since hours! >15 resources and all provide wrong information!!!

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things wrong with your request. You can’t POST data without using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Secondly, “Hello World!” isn't escaped or attached to a variable.

Following is the javascript code to POST data to the server.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = 'x='+encodeURIComponent("Hello World!");
xhr.open("POST", 'example.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send(params);
```

You can access this with `$_POST['x']` in PHP.

Alternatively, you use `$_GET['x']` by using the following code.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = encodeURIComponent("Hello World!");
xhr.open("GET", 'example.php?x='+params, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send(null);
```

GET is more in line with the idea of using `Content-type: text/plain`.

Comment: @genkidesu: I see you're new here. It's customary on this site to accept answers that you find helpful. Otherwise, people will be more reluctant to answer any future questions you may have.

Comment: @abc you should mark as accepted the Herbert reply. Hello Herbert thank you for the correct statement I was trying without success the one on [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_post2), compared with your, their one looks messed and incomplete (I'm wondering how it could work)

Comment: This is just wrong. You can use POST together with text/plain. Its just that most web resources are not explaining it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `http_get_request_body` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php)